# php array sort in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, array-multisort

I am trying to order an array produced by a foreach loop, here is my code:

```
$lowestvar = array();

foreach ($variations as $variation){
    $lowestvar[] = $variation['price_html'];            
}
```

I am then using array_multisort like this:

```
array_multisort($lowestvar, SORT_ASC);
print_r($lowestvar);
```

This works for the first looped item with a output of:

```
Array ( [0] => £10.00 [1] => £15.00 )
```

But the second array in the loop looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => £10.00 [1] => £5.00 )
```

Any ideas on where i am going wrong?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22941845/edit) your question to include the output of the following statement: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($variations, 1).'</pre>';`.

Comment: That produces a lot of code, and the majority of it is pointless to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) as like in the following example

```
 function cmp($a1, $b1)
 {
  $a=str_replace('£','',$a1);
  $b=str_replace('£','',$b1);
  if ($a == $b) {
      return 0;
    }
   return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
 }

  $a = array('£10.00','£5.00');

  usort($a, "cmp");
  print_r($a);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
  [0] => £5.00
  [1] => £10.00
 )
```

Comment: not need also to int typecasting... I hate php for this))

Comment: some explain: how can I guarantee that my strings sorted correctly, if sometimes they compared as numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You're sorting **STRINGS**, which means that `10 < 5` is true. Remember that string sorting go char-by-char, not by "entire value".

Comment: Don't let that happen again. Coffee before stack. ALWAYS.

Comment: So is there away around this?

Comment: usort(), with a callback that converts your strings to numbers for comparison purposes. But if you're getting those money values from somewhere where they are JUST numbers, then you should be storing those plain numbers. Formatted strings should only be generated at output time, never for intermediate stages liket his.